# Adding Elements to Optional Array turning up nil?

Tags: swift

So here's what I got:

- Owner Class
- Pet Class
- PetType Class

**Owner Class**

*This class simply declares a variable **pet** of type **Pet?***

```
class Owner {
  var pet: Pet?
}
```

**Pet Class**

*This class simply declares an empty array of **PetType***

```
class Pet {
  var pets = [PetType]()
}
```

**PetType Class**

*Two stored variables: **petType**(e.g. Dog), and **petName**(e.g. Harris) and a basic **init** method that takes two parameters: **petType** and **petName***

```
class PetType {
  var petType: String
  var petName: String

  init(petType: String, petName: String) {
    self.petType = petType
    self.petName = petName
  }
}
```

**Note:** This was all done in a *Playground*

```
let owner = Owner() // returns {nil}
var firstPet = PetType(petType: "Dog", petName: "Harris") // returns {petType "Dog" petName "Harris"}
owner.pet?.pets.append(firstPet) // returns nil
owner.pet?.pets[0].petName // returns nil
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are severely messing up the semantic structure of your types... `petName` should be in `Pet`, a pet can only have one pet type, and an owner can have multiple pets.

Comment: @justin rose..well...i liked the question..i was getting the same error and initialized it inline to solve it....as antonio posted the answer..but now i knew what was my actual error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Owner` has a property which is never initialized. By doing it inline:

```
class Owner {
    var pet: Pet? = Pet()
}
```

your code works as expected.

If you do not want to initialize it inline, then you have to modify the code using `Owner` accordingly:

```
let owner = Owner()
var firstPet = PetType(petType: "Dog", petName: "Harris")

owner.pet = Pet() // <-- here you have to initialize the `pet` property
owner.pet?.pets.append(firstPet)
owner.pet?.pets[0].petName
```

Comment: I would not do that in-line, because an owner does not necessarily have to have a pet.

Answer (score 2):

As pet inside the owner class is **optional**  until and unless you assign a pet object or create a pet object using init you will get nil.Optional value is **forced unwrapped with !** (it means you are damn sure that value will be present in an optional),You can use optional binding if you are not sure about the value of optional.
So the solution is:

```
 let owner = Owner()
 owner.pet = Pet()

 var firstPet = PetType(petType: "Dog", petName: "Harris")
 owner.pet!.pets.append(firstPet)
 owner.pet!.pets[0].petName
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend nor encourage using forced unwrapping for whichever reason, unless strictly needed - in my opinion is a bad practice and it causes more problems than benefits

Comment: You can use optional binding if you are not sure whether the value is present or not, in this case I'm damn sure that the value is present, Even I agree with you Antonio forced unwrapping may crash your program(App).